# How to use NSMutableRequest in XCode6

Tags: swift, nsmutableurlrequest

Code:

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: strURl, cachePolicy:NSURLRequestCachePolicy, timeoutInterval:60.0)
```

What is wrong with my code? How do I solve below error:

```
Expected member name or constructor call after type name
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSURLRequestCachePolicy` is an enum, you need to pick one of its values. You can get a list of them and what they do [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSURLRequestCachePolicy).

For example, if you want to use the default cache policy, you'd do:

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: strURl, cachePolicy:NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval:60.0)
```